# Data Attributes into Fields Value

Tags: jquery

I am struggling with adding **data-** attributes into inputs of a form by clicking on a link. If I click on another link then previous values should be replaced with new ones which are related to this link.

This is my code of the links:

```
<div id="links">
<h3>Links</h3>
<a href="#1" data-url="http://apple.com" data-name="My url">Link 1</a>
<a href="#2" data-url="http://bbc.co.uk" data-name="My second url">Link 2</a>
<a href="#3" data-url="http://google.com" data-name="My third url">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

And this is a code of my form:

```
<div id="form">
<h3>Form</h3>
<input type="text" size="25" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
</div>
```

So I have got only one form to serve all links (maybe over 100 in total).

Please see my JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtzrjrs2/1/

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why both input fields have no name? Which `data-*` attribute is for which `<input />` field?

Comment: Can i add attribute data-url into my hidden input field as as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code, annotated:

```
$('#links a').click(function(){    // when I click an 'a' element within the element with ID 'links'
    $(this).find('input').val();   //find any inputs contained within the clicked item, and get the value of the input
});
```

You probably want something more like this:

```
$('#links a').click(function(){                           // when I click an 'a' element within the element with ID 'links'
    $('#form').find('input').val($(this).data('name'));   // find any inputs within the elmeent with id 'form', and set its value to be the 'data-name' attribute of the item I clicked
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jtzrjrs2/2/)

**Update**

To set separate values in the inputs, this solution should work:

```
$('#links a').click(function(){                                        // when I click an 'a' element within element with ID 'links'
    $('#form').find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).data('name'));   // for the element with id 'form', find all inputs of type 'text', and set the value to the 'data-name' attribute of the clicked element
    $('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').val($(this).data('url'));  // for the element with id 'form', find all inputs of type 'hidden', and set the value to the 'data-url' attribute of the clicked element
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jtzrjrs2/3/)

Comment: Thank you @Dave Salomon can I add data-url into the hidden input field at the same time?

Comment: You're welcome. Hope the inline comments on the code help :).